# Get access denied using project owner service account credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an application querying activity log.
I'm using Service Account credential with Project owner role, also tried "logging admin", "private logs viewer" , "logs viewer" and "organization administrator"

Service creation code is:

```
private  Reports createActivityService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {  
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();  
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();  
    GoogleCredentials credential = createCredential(ReportsScopes.all());  
    HttpRequestInitializer httpInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credential);  
    return new Reports.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, httpInitializer).setApplicationName("My App").build();  
}  

public GoogleCredentials createCredential(Set<String> scopes) throws IOException {  
    String clientCredentialFile = <path/to/credential>credential.json;  
    InputStream clientCredentionalFIS = new FileInputStream(clientCredentialFile);  
    GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(clientCredentionalFIS);  
    if (credential.createScopedRequired() == true) {  
        credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);  
    }  
    return credential;  
}
```

Query code is:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

private List<Activity> getActivityList() throws IOException {
    Activities response = null;
    Report report = createActivityService();
    com.google.api.services.reports.Reports.Activities.List list = report.activities().list("all", "admin");
    list.setStartTime(simpleDateFormat.format(startTime));
    list.setStartTime(simpleDateFormat.format(endTime));
    List<Activity> activityList = new ArrayList<Activity>();
    do {
        response = list.execute();
        // do something
        list.setPageToken(response.getNextPageToken());
    } while (response.getNextPageToken() != null);
    return activityList;
}
```

Response is:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records.",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to take a [look at this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable).

I think your issue is cause by how the credential file is passed around.

The client library can determine [your credentials implicitly](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication)  when you set the environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" to your .json file.

[Here is an example](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-java) on how to test the credentials

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late here but for any everyone sake, you can try below:

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"

    //admin "google.golang.org/api/admin/directory/v1"
    admin "google.golang.org/api/admin/reports/v1"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

// Path to the Service Account's Private Key file
var ServiceAccountFilePath = “/path/to/keyfile.json"

// Build and returns an Admin SDK Directory service object authorized with
// the service accounts that act on behalf of the given user.
// Args:
//    user_email: The email of the user. Needs permissions to access the Admin APIs.
// Returns:
//    Admin SDK directory service object.
func CreateReportsService(userEmail string) (*admin.Service, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    jsonCredentials, err := ioutil.ReadFile(ServiceAccountFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(jsonCredentials, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("JWTConfigFromJSON: %v", err)
    }
    config.Subject = userEmail

    ts := config.TokenSource(ctx)

    srv, err := admin.NewService(ctx, option.WithTokenSource(ts))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("NewService: %v", err)
    }
    return srv, nil
}

func main() {
    srv, err := CreateReportsService(“<admin_user_email_id>") // Here please enter the admin user email id; it is the admin user who has the permission
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve reports Client %v", err)
        return
    }

    var userKey = "all"
    //var appName = "admin"
    var appName = "login"
    //var appName = "token"
    r, err := srv.Activities.List(userKey, appName).MaxResults(10).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve logins to domain: userKey=%s, appName=%s, error: %v", userKey, appName, err)
        return
    }

    if len(r.Items) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No logins found.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Logins:")
        for _, a := range r.Items {
            t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, a.Id.Time)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Unable to parse login time.")
                // Set time to zero.
                t = time.Time{}
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s: %s %s\n", t.Format(time.RFC822), a.Actor.Email,
                a.Events[0].Name)
        }
    }
}
```